# Is it possible to initiate "delete from iCloud" from iPhone?

Tags: icloud, itunes-match

I know, from within iTunes one can chose to remove an item from iCloud. Is the same possible from the iPhone?

Say you imported an album full os songs and don't like one or two and would like to delete it from iCloud directly from the iPhone.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

No, the song can only be deleted from iTunes on Mac or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

### No - this isn't a function that exists today.

You can't download it from the iCloud, but if you've downloaded the song on your iPhone, you can delete the song. Swipe to the right on the song and there will be shown a delete button where you can delete the song from your iPhone and by so, saving space!

[image]

If you don't want all your iCloud music be shown in the overview, check off "show all music" in your settings.

Sorry for the Dutch language in the screenshots. But I hope the red bar will make everything clear.

[image]

Comment: Not showing a song on an iOS device is different from being able to delete it from the iCloud store from an iOS device. Am I missing that step somewhere in the answer? It's a nice answer - just doesn't seem fit for this question.

Comment: No, that's right. I started the answer with 'it can't be done', so I'm offering him a way where he doesn't see his entire iCloud library.

Comment: Aah - I was distracted by all the shiny pictures ;-)

Comment: Haha :-) That's what I figured. But you're right it doesn't answer his question. If you like, you can remove the post.

Comment: I wouldn't - it's full odd good - I'll try editing the beginning to hit us all on the head with the NO, but...

Comment: Nicely done! :)